# $2^{\log_{10}n} = n^{\log_{10}2}$ How are those equal?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

How are they equal? And if given $2^{\log_{10}n}$, what are the steps to convert to $n^{\log_{10}2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the $\log_{10}$ of both sides.

$\log_{10}(2^{\log_{10}n}) = \log_{10}n\cdot \log_{10}2$

and similarly the right side

note, $\log_{10}$ is a strict monotonic on $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, do you know how we can convert from 1 expression to the other?

Comment: you take $\log$, than apply exponent, like $2^{\log_{10}n} = 10^{\log_{10}(2^{\log_{10}n})} = 10^{\log_{10}n \cdot \log_{10}2} = n^{\log_{10}2}$